# Queue implementation with Linked list in C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, linked-list, queue, singly-linked-list

I am trying to implement Queue container in C++ based on a linked list. I used the same structure to implement Stack and it worked fine.

But now I havet trouble with the method "enqueue". I can't understand what exactly is the problem, although I know that pointers are my weak point.

```
#include <iostream>

template <class N>
class node {
public:
  N data;
  node* next;
};

template <class Q>
class my_queue {
protected:
  node<Q>* m_head;
  unsigned int m_size;

public:
  my_queue() {
    m_head = NULL;
    m_size = 0;
  }

  void enqueue(Q value) {

    node<Q>* newel = new node<Q>; // creating the new element
    node<Q>* last = m_head; // find the last element in the queue

    while(last != NULL) {
      last = last->next;
    }

    newel->data = value;
    newel->next = last->next;
    last->next = newel;

    m_size++;
  }

  void print() {
    node<Q>* element = m_head; // element == each element in the list
    while(element != NULL) {
      std::cout << element->data << std::endl;
      element = element->next;
    }
  }

};
```

If I compile this with:

```
main() {
  my_queue<int> q;
  q.enqueue(1);
  q.enqueue(2);
  q.enqueue(3);
  q.enqueue(4);
  q.enqueue(5);
  q.print();

  return 0;
}
```

I get no errors, but when I run it I get "Segmentation fault".

Comment: When you insert the first element, `last` will be `m_head`, which was never allocated, so you cannot do `last->next = newel`.

Comment: thanks that was part of the solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After this loop in the function

```
while(last != NULL) {
  last = last->next;
}
```

the pointer `last` will be always equal to `NULL`. So the function has undefined behavior due to these statements

```
newel->next = last->next;
last->next = newel;
```

The function can be rewritten the following way

```
void enqueue( const Q &value ) 
{
    node<Q> *newel = new node<Q> { value, nullptr };

    if ( m_head == nullptr )
    {
        m_head = newel;
    }
    else
    {
        node<Q> *last = m_head; // find the last element in the queue

        while ( last->next != nullptr ) last = last->next;

        last->next = newel;
    }

    m_size++;
}
```

To make the queue more efficient it is better to implement it based on a two-sided list.

Comment: Great, thanks :)

Funny, before you added your the revised code, I rewrote it in the exact same way after reading your comment :)

Comment: What do you mean by two sided list?

Comment: @0x499602D2 It is a singly-linked list that has the tail pointer. Thus new nodes can be added to any side of the list.

Comment: My example is a single linked list (each node has only one link to another element, i.e. "next"). A node in a double linked list would have two links: "next" and "previous".

See: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Doubly_linked_list

Comment: @vgratian You could add one more node the tail node to your queue. In this case adding new nodes to the tail of the queue would be much more efficient.